# Managing dependencies in JSPM / SysyemJS across bundles

Tags: webpack, systemjs, jspm

I am using JSPM + SystemJS to manage dependencies and to bundle my projects.

**Context (TL;DR)**

I have distributed architecture where a single page application on initialisation uses System.import to load in additional external resources, let’s call these resources “widgets”. These widgets are independent and can be shared across multiple single page applications. All of these applications and widgets have their own independent development / deployment life cycle.

[Single page application and widget relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTNf.png)

Both the SPAs and the widgets are bundled with their own library dependencies with a few exceptions that need to be the exact same instance because they need to be singletons. For instance, React doesn’t like it when there are multiple instances present or PostalJS, (an in-memory event bus) can only send event within the same instance.

[Event bus communicating with multiple components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNi4.png)

SystemJS maps to a particular library with a specific version number and the compiled bundles have the version number compiled into their internal library reference.

This in itself isn’t a problem and is actually a good design decision, especially for me since I want to have multiple bundles coexisting in the same application context and they could potentially use conflicting versions of the same library. But it does become a problem when I need to share an *instance* of a dependency because even a patch update would require me to upgrade and redeploy all of the applications and widgets.

**Actual Question**

The question is whether there is a good solution for dealing with shared dependencies across independent SystemJS bundles.

Ideally I would like to have the SPA dictate the version of the dependency and the "widgets" use the version that has been provided to them. I managed to let the SystemJS expose a dependency as a Global in the SPA.

```
SystemJS.config({
   meta: {
     "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js": {
        "exports": "React",
        "format": "global"
     }
  },
  ...
})
```

But I have not figured out how to map a Global variable back into SystemJS in the widgets.

I am open to alternative suggestions if you have them.